# Error installing Fasttext on Windows 10 Python 3

Tags: cygwin, windows-10, anaconda, python-3.5, fasttext

I am trying to install fastText using pip install fastText on Windows 10. I have Python 3 installed in Anaconda.
I tried reading several posts but they do not give a clear idea about what exact changes should I make to install. I am getting the following error:
[image]

The error shown below reads:

```
raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

Can anybody help in this?

Comment: any response? ??

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a know bug currently in open status according to [Python Bug Tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue25251)

Answer (score -1):

I am just successful install fasttext on windows 10 using pip with Visual Studio Build Tools(MS Compiler) for Visual Studio 2017.

You can download MS Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 here: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools